# SPI Module with SCK same as SPI Module Clock - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, spi

Since I see only SPI modules that have an input clock of 2xSCK I want to ask if it's possible to realize an SPI module that have an SCK of same frequency as SPI module.

Answer (score 0):

Having input `clock >= 2×SCK` is a physical boundary. It's called the Nyquist rate.

Have a look for [Shannons sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you are the SPI master or slave, you may be able to come up with something, but the best solution would be to simply increase your clock rate.  If your hardware supports them you can use DDR (double data rate) input or output registers to register inputs or drive outputs on both clock edges.  If you're the slave you can assign the SPI clock as a clock input, and latch the data using the incoming clock edge.  However you will then have to cross clock domains inside your logic.
I would highly recommend increasing your logic clock rate if at all possible.